# How to calculate total distance traveled for a group, with multiple lat longs per group?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data like the following:

| id | timestamp | lat | lon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1622062800000 | 9.5470 | 39.6191 |
| A | 1633062800000 | 9.5466 | 39.6194 |
| A | 1845062800000 | 9.5468 | 39.6190 |
| B | 1622149200000 | 9.5502 | 39.6185 |
| B | 1415260500000 | 9.5513 | 39.6190 |

I'd like to calculate the total distance traveled by each `id` and the difference between the first and last timestamp for that `id`. Something like this:

| id | total_dist_mi | total_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 243 | 223000000000 |
| B | 124 | 206888700000 |

Update:

I tried:

```
SELECT id, SUM(ST_Distance_Sphere(lat, lon)) OVER (PARTITION BY dcid ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS running_total
FROM group7ca7b23d9c014299b960de98de6eeb29.d6_visit
GROUP BY id;
```

But got this error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Expression #1 of PARTITION BY or ORDER BY clause of window '<unnamed window>' is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.table.timestamp' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: I don't know where to start.

Comment: Is the column ID or DCID? You are selecting ID but grouping by DCID.

Comment: how would you compute the distance?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate distance with `ST_Distance_Sphere` you need 2 points, so to make it work you need to calculate distance from point with previous `lat`, `lon` values to the point with current `lat`, `lon` values (if to be more precise, point should be constructed with `lon`, `lat`).

Also you need to get the previous `timestamp` value for each row to calculate the time ellapsed to move from point to point.

As you cannot use one window function in another, i.e. `LAG` (to get previous values) with `SUM` (to get the totals), you can use a CTE to obtain the distance and the ellapsed time and finally summarize them to get totals.

So the query would be like this

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        ST_Distance_Sphere(
            point(LAG(lon) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp), LAG(lat) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp)),
            point(lon, lat)
        ) AS distance_m,
        timestamp - LAG(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) AS time
    FROM data 
)
SELECT
    id,
    SUM(distance_m) / 1609.344 AS total_dist_mi,
    SUM(time) AS total_time
FROM cte
GROUP BY id
```

You can check a working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=48af96655496bf14dfda84f7b1e9d19e)